Rearranging the Collatz Sequence
In the case of the Collatz Conjecture, which states that

"If a term is even, the next term is one half of it.
If a term is odd, the next term is $3$ times the previous term plus $1$.
The conjecture is that these sequences always reach $1$, no matter  which positive integer is chosen to start the sequence", according to Wikipedia.
I would like to ask the following:

Let's say you take any random natural number $m$, and then do only the odd part of the conjecture, disregarding if the number is odd or
even, until you reach a number that is any power of $2$.
\begin{align}
& \mbox{So}\ a_{0} = m\ \mbox{and}\
a_{n} = 3a_{n - 1} + 1
\\[5mm]
& \mbox{The general form would then be:}\ 
\\ & a_{n} = \left(a_{0} + \frac{1}{2}\right)3^{n}
 - \frac{1}{2}
\\[5mm]
& \mbox{Can we somehow show that for any given}\ a_{0}
\\ & \mbox{we can find}\ k\ \mbox{and}\ n\ \mbox{so that:}
\\
& 2^{k} = a_{n} = \left(a_{0} + \frac{1}{2}\right) 3^{n} - \frac{1}{2}\ ?.
\end{align}
If we can, can this be used to somehow help towards proving the Collatz Conjecture ?.



I understand this problem and the Conjecture work differently, where in the conjecture you have an even number after every odd number in the sequence.
The way I think about it is that this idea somehow rearranges the sequence, until it reaches a power of $2$, then it collapses to $1$.

Note $2^k=\left(a_0+\frac{1}{2}\right)\cdot 3^n-\frac{1}{2}$ is equivalent to $2^{k+1}+1=(2a_0+1)\cdot 3^n$, and consider $a_0=3$.
